# How to use a custom ConfirmationURL with @supabase/auth-ui-react?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, email, supabase

I'm building a React app with the Auth component from `@supabase/auth-ui-react`, and I want to take the user to a specific path after they click the email confirmation link on signup.

Is there any way to do this with the Auth component?

I tried using the `redirectTo` prop and tried specifying the path in the `Site URL` and `Redirect URLs` on the `Supabase dashboard`, but none of these seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I only included the path in redirectTo, which works for sign in but doesn't work for sign up. Using the full URL worked.